# how to decrease memory and speed up if there is a huge dictionary in python?

Tags: python, macos, list, dictionary, memory

I want to look up a dictionary which value(string) has special words and take keys. The dictionary has dumped load into several files(any of which is several hundred maga bytes, so the sum of them is in order of GBs). so the speed is too slow, could you have any better way to speed up programs?my code is as follows:

```
teachertag=['K', 'curriculum', 'School', 'childhood', ]

import pickle
import re
import os
import time
start_time = time.time()


itemlist2=[]
for i in document:
    with open (i, 'rb') as fp:
        itemlist = pickle.load(fp)
        itemlist2+=itemlist



teacher=[]
parentandstudent=[]
parentandstudenttweet=[]
teachertweet=[]
allpeople=[]
i=0
for user in itemlist2:    
    if user.lang == 'en' and user.description!='':
        allpeople+=[user.screen_name]
        wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  user.description).split()
        k=0
        for j in wordList:
            k+=1
            if j in teachertag:
                teacher+=[user.screen_name]
                teachertweet+=[user.description]

                break
        else:
            parentandstudent+=[user.screen_name]
            parentandstudenttweet+=[user.description]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @andy. Please read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Consider a database solution instead, or maybe `shelve` https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html